# How should a minimize-to-tray application behave?

Tags: user-behavior, windows-os

I am building an application that minimizes to tray on the close-button (cross upper right corner). I found two different behaviours for this kind of application now:

1. click on the tray icon to bring the application back to front again, and not use a `ContextMenu`.
2. use a `ContextMenu` with a "Show Application" option (plus Quit and some control actions).

The first one is obviously the easiest to implement, but what is the way to go for "least surprise" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This really depends on the usage behavior of your app.

If you're able to provide some direct helpful actions in the "ContextMenu" then please use a contextmenu on click. So the user is able to interact with your app without opening it (= fast access). Best example would be the power mode of Windows 8.1, see screenshot.
[image: Windows 8.1 energy options]

Here is the Windows 10 screenshot.

[image]

If you're just showing some options (like "Open"/"Settings"/"Quit"..) then please always open the open on a click. Implement a right-click behavior to open the ContextMenu. It is really destracting if you would like to open an app and you always need to click twice (Click on tray icon -> Click on open app).

Comment: As an aside, how is that window you show in your example called? Trying to look for information on how to implement that.

Comment: Your example from Windows 8.1 is so yesterday. :o  Actually, I'm making a joke because Windows 10 was released yesterday. ;)

Comment: @JeromeR you're right, it's important to be up to date :) See the updated post above :)
at Bart: it is called ContextMenu. Here is an example for the Systray ContextMenu http://stackoverflow.com/questions/718386/how-can-i-use-the-windows-looknfeel-for-a-system-tray-context-menu