# Standard for using the system tray?

Tags: desktop-application, close, window, window-management

I'm building an application which will be "running in the system tray" (an icon will be shown there) and a menu will be shown when the user clicks on the icon

When I look at different applications I can see that there is a difference in how they use the system tray, in two respects:

#### 1. Menu

Menus are shown on right click for some applications, and on left click for others

[image: menu]

#### 2. Minimizing to tray

Some Applications are minimized to tray when clicking on "x"/"close" (in the upper right corner normally), while others are minimized to tray when the user pressed the "minimize" button

[image: close and minimize]

---

**Question: Is there a standard for how to handle the system tray?**

The application that I'm working on is cross-platform (Gnome, KDE, Windows, MacOS) and uses Qt

Grateful for help!

These other questions bring up minimize to tray behavior:

- [How should a minimize-to-tray application behave?](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/82141/how-should-a-minimize-to-tray-application-behave)
- [Close and minimize button behavior for my desktop application](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/107459/close-and-minimize-button-behavior-for-my-desktop-application)

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer:** There is **no standard**, neither between different OSes, nor within the apps of the same OS. Please find bellow full-explanation and suggested approach:

The *system tray* houses a set of special applications (application helpers, applets) that are supposed to *visibly run in the background*. This is a contradiction, which encourages inconsistencies to the interaction with the system tray apps.

The above behaviour categorises the system tray somewhere between the *task bar*  (includes visible user applications) and the *task manager* (includes all user-system tasks visible and non-visible). The hybrid nature of the system tray applications (partly task-bar, partly task-manager) encourages non-standard interaction designs like those that you describe (left-click for context menu and 'x' for minimising).

As a remedy, when there is **no standard**, then the employment of **consistency** might be helpful for the users. For example, a context menu appears only with right-click and the application is only minimised with the minimise button. In the same way, pressing the 'x' brings up a dialog that asks the user to confirm quitting the application and left-clicking brings-up the main application window (if there is any).

Answer (score 0):

On Windows when I click the X on an opened app I want to close it. I personally find it infuriating when some apps *cough*Skype*cough* just minimize to my task bar. Since your app lives in the tray the X should just make the window disappear and your app continues to run in the tray, a menu option from the tray should be "Quit/Exit" to kill the app completely.

TL;DR use `X` to close and if you need some form of minimize it should be a different icon.